# multiline textfield question in flutter web?

Tags: flutter

I use multiline textfield in flutter web,but I can't use mouse to select the second line.I only can select the first line...How to solve this problem?
here is my simple code.

```
TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '正文',
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: try asking this in flutter github. You can file a bug

Comment: I don't think that's how multi-line works... Basically, in multi-line, u have the option to have 'multi-line' entries, basically by pressing enter or when it overflows. Whereas pressing 'enter' on any other TextInputType results in that field going out of focus

Comment: yes,I use textfield because I want to make a website that other people can upload their article.Are there any other solution that can replace textfield?